# Cannot dynamically add items to React Native RNPickerSelect View

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a disease search endpoint which based on what the user types in, it will search diseases which match the search name. For instance if I want to search for tumors it will return all relavent cancers. However, I would like to then populate a RNPickerSelect box with the diseases returned back from the server. However I am unable to add theses diseases to the RNPickerSelect box. Instead I get the following error:

`Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Here is my User.js file:

```
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';

const UserLandingPage = ({navigation}) => {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [errorVisible, setErrorVisible] = useState(false);
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");
  const [successVisible, setSuccessVisible] = useState(false);
  const [disease, setDisease] = useState("");
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
  var placeholder = {
        label: 'Select Disease...',
        value: null,
      };
  var options= [];
  const searchDiseases = async() => {
    const url = constants.serverUrl + 'app/getDiseaseName' + '?diseaseName=' + disease;
    let result = fetch(url, {
                       method: "GET"
     }).then(response => response.json())
       .then(response => {
       options= [];
       if (response.diseases) {
            response.diseases.map( (disease) => {
                options.push(new Object({label:disease.name[0] , value:disease.key_id}));
                <RNPickerSelect.Item label={disease.name[0]} value={disease.key_id}/>
            });
            setErrorVisible(false);
       } else {
           console.warn("Error retrieving Disease " + response.message);
           setErrorMessage("Error! " + response.message );
           setErrorVisible(true);
       }
      });
}
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.TextInput}
          placeholder="Disease."
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
          onChangeText={(disease) => setDisease(disease)}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <Text>Select Disease</Text>
        <RNPickerSelect
          placeholder={placeholder}
          items={options}
          onValueChange={(value) => setSelectedValue(value)}
          value={selectedValue}
        />
        {selectedValue && <Text>Selected: {selectedValue}</Text>}
      </View>
      {errorVisible ? (
                        <View style={{ color: 'red'}}>
                          <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 18 }}>{errorMessage}</Text>
                        </View>
                      ) : null}

      {successVisible ? (
                          <View style={{ color: 'blue'}}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'blue', fontSize: 18 }}>{successMessage}</Text>
                          </View>
                        ) : null}
      <TouchableOpacity>
          <Button
                title="Search Disease"
                onPress={searchDiseases}
           />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

It seems the error is the result of trying to add the diseases to the <RNPickerSelect.Item> component. Does anyone know how to update a RNPicker items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by defining an array of disease items which were returned from the server. I defined a variable of disease item options and then attached to the RNPickerSelect object.

```
const UserLandingPage = ({navigation}) => {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [errorVisible, setErrorVisible] = useState(false);
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");
  const [successVisible, setSuccessVisible] = useState(false);
  const [disease, setDisease] = useState("");
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  var placeholder = {
        label: 'Select Disease...',
        value: null,
      };
  //var options= [];
  const searchDiseases = async() => {
    const url = constants.serverUrl + 'app/getDiseaseName' + '?diseaseName=' + disease;
    console.warn(url);
    let result = fetch(url, {
                       method: "GET"
     }).then(response => response.json())
       .then(response => {
       setOptions([]);
       optionsTemp = [];
       if (response.diseases) {
            response.diseases.map( (disease) => {
                optionsTemp.push(new Object({label:disease.name[0] , value: disease.key_id}));
            });
        setOptions(optionsTemp);
        setErrorVisible(false);
       } else {
           console.warn("Error retrieving Disease " + response.message);
           setErrorMessage("Error! " + response.message );
           setErrorVisible(true);
       }
      });
}
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.TextInput}
          placeholder="Disease."
          placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
          onChangeText={(disease) => setDisease(disease)}
          onKeyPress={searchDiseases}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <Text>Select Disease</Text>
        <RNPickerSelect
          placeholder={placeholder}
          items={options}
          onValueChange={(value) => setSelectedValue(value)}
          value={selectedValue}
        />
        {selectedValue && <Text>Selected: {selectedValue}</Text>}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
           <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} >
                 <DatePicker label="Start Date."
                   selected={startDate} />
           </LocalizationProvider>
       </View>
      {errorVisible ? (
                        <View style={{ color: 'red'}}>
                          <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 18 }}>{errorMessage}</Text>
                        </View>
                      ) : null}

      {successVisible ? (
                          <View style={{ color: 'blue'}}>
                            <Text style={{ color: 'blue', fontSize: 18 }}>{successMessage}</Text>
                          </View>
                        ) : null}
      <TouchableOpacity>
          <Button
                title="Add Disease"
              />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```